# increment row number when value of column changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need help in writing a query in SQL server 2012 for the following data. The data is sorted by date.

```
 Person     DEVICE   DATE  
------     ---   
person1    D1       1/1/2015
person1    D1       5/1/2015
person1    D2       6/1/2015
person1    D2       10/1/2015
person1    D1       11/1/2015
person1    D1       16/1/2015
person1    D2       17/1/2015
person1    D2       20/1/2015
```

I need to have a GN column that gets incremented whenever the DEVICE value changes. My result should look as below

```
GN       Person    DEVICE        DATE  
---     ------     -----       -------
 1      person1    D1          1/1/2015       
 1      person1    D1          5/1/2015             
 2      person1    D2          6/1/2015             
 2      person1    D2          10/1/2015             
 3      person1    D1          11/1/2015             
 3      person1    D1          16/1/2015             
 4      person1    D2          17/1/2015             
 4      person1    D2          20/1/2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using the lag function in a case statement. The lag function will allow you to compare a current row value with its predecessor.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: I would point out you could also use the OVER clause, in case you had a pre-2012 version.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx